# Appending Quotations in Text File to Each line

Tags: python, append

I'm sure this isn't too difficult but I'm not seeing it.  I need to add single quotation marks to all the lines in a text file as well as add ",text" straight after the quotation.

so I would have

```
text = xxx (start)
text = 'xxx',text (finish)
```

so something like:

```
`yourstring = ''.join((''''yourstring',''', 'text'))
```

which gives the correct output, I'm just not sure how to do this for all of the lines in the text file?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read "file" in read mode, create new temp file, write each line in new temp file (concate `'` and other `text` as well) and delete old 'file' then rename 'temp' to 'file' name(read comment in following code at each line):

```
with open("file") as i: # open file for reading, i = input file 
  with open("temp", "w") as o: # open temp file in write mode, o = output 
     for l in i: # read line by line  
         o.write("'%s',text\n" % l[:-1]) # concate ' and text 
          #       ^  ^ added `'` for each line  
os.remove("file") # delete old file. Note:this is not needed in postfix system 
os.rename("temp", "file")  # rename file
```

Edit: If you wants to read file completely in a buffer and use `join( )` to add `'sometext'` string. Then you can do as follows (this I believe unnecessary complicated ):

```
with open('file') as f:
  file_date = f.read()
updated_file_data = "sometext\n".join(map("'{0}'".format, file_date.split('\n')))
```

Comment: my perception is the write line should be `o.write("'%s',text\n" % l[:-1])`  - i.e., put whole original line in quotes.  And on my system, os.remove() isn't needed before os.rename() - are there cases where it is?

Comment: @RoryYorke your first I idea is nice. I tried in Linux `mv` command it replace 'file' 's old contents. I update my answer Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of pointers about the above answer:

you can of course att all the new text in go with

```
o.write("'"+l[:-1]+"' yourtext\n")
```

Comment: to match answer do `("'" + l[:-1] + "' yourtext\n")`. If I am correct OP  also wants `'` before line starts.